# How to keep downloading tweets with rtweet package but also being able to use R Studio for other tasks

Tags: r, api, twitter, streaming, rtweet

Have just installed the rtweet package and have started downloading tweets. I want to collect tweets that contain the word corruption for the next 20 weeks. However the streaming and downloading of tweets keeps R busy and I can not use it for other tasks. Is there a way to stop the streaming and continue again, picking up at the point in time where I left off?

My current code looks like this and it works well:

```
library(rtweet)

consumer_key <- "xxxxxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret <- "xxxxxxxxx"
create_token(app = "xxxxx", consumer_key, consumer_secret, set_renv = TRUE)

twentyweeks <- 60L * 60L * 24L * 7L * 20L
corruption <- "Corruption"
stream_tweets2(q = corruption, parse = FALSE, timeout = twentyweeks, dir = "corruption-stream", append = TRUE)


rt <- parse_stream("stream-1.json")
```

A further but related question would be if I can take a random sample of tweets every day in this period of 20 weeks. I have the feeling that if I keep downloading all tweets that include the word corruption I will end up with a database that is a few times larger than my local memory (but that could also be a wildly mistaken estimate).

Thank you very much in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and managed by using another modest computer device i.e. raspberry pi 3 to only stream and store twitter data. I just install the R software on it along with rtweet package. Then I `source()` my script to stream the data using:

```
`stream_tweets2(
                q = "your,keywords,please",
                #languange = "id",  # not really works
                parse = FALSE, 
                timeout = 7L * 24L * 60L * 60L,
                dir = "/your/dir/path/here",
                append = T  # arg will append new file for every 10.000 
                            # tweets streamed with a different file name
               )`
```

because the files will be stored for every 10.000 tweets, I will get several files that I could sample for next processing. Currently, I use my VNC to transfer the files to my processing-laptop. You could also manage to automatically upload the streamed data to a cloud if you want to.

P.S:
Installing R on raspberry pi 3 will encounter you with some more manual library installations for raspbian.
Using official repo almost only install an outdated version of R. For me on 18 April 2018, it can only install R ver. 3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a whole other computer. You can have multiple R instances and run them independently. Your `stream_tweets2` should save tweets to a file that you will read in another instance.